# How do I configure reactor-netty to use SSL?

Tags: spring, ssl, netty, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to get familiar with Spring's Project Reactor (https://projectreactor.io/) and have built a small application to make REST calls to another service over SSL. I cannot find any way to configure the `org.springframework.web.client.reactive.WebClient` to make requests over SSL. There seems to be no documentation about this.  I am using `reactor-core` 3.0.0.RC1 and `reactor-netty` 0.5.0.M3, and Spring Framework 5.0.0.M1. Does anyone know how to configure `reactor-netty` with SSL support?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2017-01-04:**

*This was corrected in the 5.0.0.M4 release of Spring Framework with [this patch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/64bc0ca744781af2bf96412ced0f439fc98ee00d).*

**Original Answer:**

I discovered that the solution is to create a new `ClientHttpConnector` implementation that respects SSL.

```
public class ReactorClientHttpsAwareConnector implements ClientHttpConnector {

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientHttpResponse> connect(HttpMethod method, URI uri,
                                            Function<? super ClientHttpRequest, Mono<Void>> requestCallback) {

        return reactor.ipc.netty.http.HttpClient.create()
                                                .request(io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMethod.valueOf(method.name()),
                                                    uri.toString(),
                                                    httpClientRequest -> requestCallback
                                                        .apply(new ReactorClientHttpRequest(method, uri, httpClientRequest)))
                                                .cast(HttpInbound.class)
                                                .otherwise(HttpException.class, exc -> Mono.just(exc.getChannel()))
                                                .map(ReactorClientHttpResponse::new);
    }
}
```

`HttpClient.create()` is required to make the client SSL-aware.